# SecurityContext is not getting cleared when using SpringBootTest with TestNG

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, testng

I am working on a SpringBoot application. I am running integration tests on REST APIs using SpringBooTest and TestNG. It is a stateless application. Sessions are not stored.

**Context**

I have filter that explicitly sets the authentication object into SecurityContext like below

```
Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(contextUser, "", null);
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
// Continue to app.
```

After this point, I am not using any authentication manager as the token is already validated. I am not explicitly clearing the security context any where.

**Problem**

When I run a couple of tests from SpringBootTest, the second test still has access to security context set in the first test. When I ran the test in debug mode, I can see `SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();` getting called from `SecurityContextPersistenceFilter` which means context should be cleared.

How do I solve this issue? I would think security context should be always cleared after the request is complete and should not be available for the next test.

Comment: Do all requests pass through the security chain? If some of them don't pass through the securty chain but your filter is still invoked, you are basically have a leak.

Comment: I set permitAll() for a `/authenticate`. The resource class of `/authenticate` calls authentication manager and sets the security context. Looks like it will not pass through security chain for permitAll ? This `/authenticate` request does not go through filter mentioned in OP also because it is configured as `http.addFilterBefore(customFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to set a `FilterChainProxy` like below for the filters to get executed in Spring Integration test, which would take care of clearing the context.

```
restLoginMockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(loginResource).setControllerAdvice(exceptionTranslator)
            .apply(springSecurity(springSecurityFilterChain)).build();
```